# How can I calculate and display the download speed per file?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
private void DownloadFile() {

  if (_downloadUrls.Any()) {
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.DownloadProgressChanged += client_DownloadProgressChanged;
    client.DownloadFileCompleted += client_DownloadFileCompleted;

    var url = _downloadUrls.Dequeue();
    string startTag = "animated/";
    string endTag = "/infra";

    int index = url.IndexOf(startTag);
    int index1 = url.IndexOf(endTag);

    string fname = url.Substring(index + 9, index1 - index - 9);
    client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), @"C:\Temp\tempframes\" + fname + ".gif");

    lastDownloadedFile = @"C:\Temp\tempframes\" + fname + ".gif";
    label1.Text = url;
    return;
  }

  // End of the download
  btnStart.Text = "Download Complete";
}

private void client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e) {
  if (e.Error != null) {
    // handle error scenario
    throw e.Error;
  }
  if (e.Cancelled) {
    // handle cancelled scenario
  }

  Image img = new Bitmap(lastDownloadedFile);
  Image[] frames = GetFramesFromAnimatedGIF(img);
  foreach(Image image in frames) {
    countFrames++;
    image.Save(@"C:\Temp\tempframes\" + countFrames + ".gif");
  }

  DownloadFile();
}

void client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e) {
  double bytesIn = double.Parse(e.BytesReceived.ToString());
  double totalBytes = double.Parse(e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString());
  double percentage = bytesIn / totalBytes * 100;
  pBarFileProgress.Value = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage).ToString());
  label1.Text = e.BytesReceived.ToString() + "/" + e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString();
}
```

Now I added this method

```
DateTime lastUpdate;
long lastBytes = 0;

private void progressChanged(long bytes) {
  if (lastBytes == 0) {
    lastUpdate = DateTime.Now;
    lastBytes = bytes;
    return;
  }

  var now = DateTime.Now;
  var timeSpan = now - lastUpdate;
  var bytesChange = bytes - lastBytes;
  var bytesPerSecond = bytesChange / timeSpan.Seconds;

  lastBytes = bytes;
  lastUpdate = now;
}
```

And I want to use this method or another method to display the download speed in the progresschanged event on label2. But I'm not sure how to use this method.

Not sure how to use with it in the progresschanged event.

Comment: Well generally `Bytes Per Second = Bytes in last packet / Seconds since previous Packet` so that looks correct. Smooth it out a bit (e.g. by keeping the last 10 values and displaying an average) and you have your download speed.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer if you can show me how to do it ? Thank you.

Comment: Sure, I'll put together a short example, be right back.

Comment: I've edited my answer, should contain everything you need to get started now. The implementation is a bit quick and dirty so it will probably not work for simultanious downloads or multi-threaded use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to your prepared method `progressChanged` would best fit into `client_DownloadProgressChanged` like this:

```
progressChanged(e.BytesReceived);
```

You must however use `TotalSeconds` instead of `Seconds` or the values will not be correct and also cause a division by zero exception

```
var bytesPerSecond = bytesChange / timeSpan.TotalSeconds;
```

This helper class will keep track of received chunks, timestamps and progress for you:

```
public class DownloadProgressTracker
{
    private long _totalFileSize;
    private readonly int _sampleSize;
    private readonly TimeSpan _valueDelay;

    private DateTime _lastUpdateCalculated;
    private long _previousProgress;

    private double _cachedSpeed;

    private Queue<Tuple<DateTime, long>> _changes = new Queue<Tuple<DateTime, long>>();

    public DownloadProgressTracker(int sampleSize, TimeSpan valueDelay)
    {
        _lastUpdateCalculated = DateTime.Now;
        _sampleSize = sampleSize;
        _valueDelay = valueDelay;
    }

    public void NewFile()
    {
        _previousProgress = 0;
    }

    public void SetProgress(long bytesReceived, long totalBytesToReceive)
    {
        _totalFileSize = totalBytesToReceive;

        long diff = bytesReceived - _previousProgress;
        if (diff <= 0)
            return;

        _previousProgress = bytesReceived;

        _changes.Enqueue(new Tuple<DateTime, long>(DateTime.Now, diff));
        while (_changes.Count > _sampleSize)
            _changes.Dequeue();
    }

    public double GetProgress()
    {
        return _previousProgress / (double) _totalFileSize;
    }

    public string GetProgressString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0:P0}", GetProgress());
    }

    public string GetBytesPerSecondString()
    {
        double speed = GetBytesPerSecond();
        var prefix = new[] { "", "K", "M", "G"};

        int index = 0;
        while (speed > 1024 && index < prefix.Length - 1)
        {
            speed /= 1024;
            index++;
        }

        int intLen = ((int) speed).ToString().Length;
        int decimals = 3 - intLen;
        if (decimals < 0)
            decimals = 0;

        string format = String.Format("{{0:F{0}}}", decimals) + "{1}B/s";

        return String.Format(format, speed, prefix[index]);
    }

    public double GetBytesPerSecond()
    {
        if (DateTime.Now >= _lastUpdateCalculated + _valueDelay)
        {
            _lastUpdateCalculated = DateTime.Now;
            _cachedSpeed = GetRateInternal();
        }

        return _cachedSpeed;
    }

    private double GetRateInternal()
    {
        if (_changes.Count == 0)
            return 0;

        TimeSpan timespan = _changes.Last().Item1 - _changes.First().Item1;
        long bytes = _changes.Sum(t => t.Item2);

        double rate = bytes / timespan.TotalSeconds;

        if (double.IsInfinity(rate) || double.IsNaN(rate))
            return 0;

        return rate;
    }
}
```

In the following example, the progress tracker will give you the average download rate of the last `50` received Packets but only every `500` ms (so the UI doesn't flicker). You might need to tinker with the values a bit to find a good balance between accuracy and smoothness.

```
//Somewhere in your constructor / initializer:
tracker = new DownloadProgressTracker(50, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));

void client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    tracker.SetProgress(e.BytesReceived, e.TotalBytesToReceive);
    pBarFileProgress.Value = tracker.GetProgress() * 100;
    label1.Text = e.BytesReceived + "/" + e.TotalBytesToReceive;
    label2.Text = tracker.GetBytesPerSecondString();
}
```

Keep in mind, that you have to reset the tracker before or after every new file:

```
tracker.NewFile();
```

---

In case you need some bigger files to test this with, I've found some [here](http://www.thinkbroadband.com/download.html)

Comment: I'm getting error on the line tracker = new DownloadProgressTracker.DownloadProgress(e.TotalBytesToReceive, 50, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500)); Severity Code Description 'DownloadProgressTracker.DownloadProgress' does not contain a constructor that takes 3 arguments

Comment: Just to make clear, The DownloadProgressTracker.DownloadProgress is since i created a new class. I called the new class DownloadProgressTracker and the helper is DownloadProgress.

Comment: @DanielHalfoni I just realized I copied code from two different versions. The updated code should work.

Comment: It seems to be working fine. I changed the line of the progressBar cast it to (int) if not i'm getting error cant convert double to int. pBarFileProgress.Value = (int)tracker.GetProgress() * 100; another small thing it seems like that the progressBar is updating from 0 to 100 at once after it's updating the labels 1&2.  I wonder if it's possible to make that the progressBar will be update in real time with the labels ? But it's working fine.

Comment: What i mean is that first i see the label1 and label2 updating when they finish then i see the progressBar moving from 0 to 100% then the next file same thing. First it's updating the labels then after a second or so it's updating the progressBar and i think the progressBar should be updating/progress in real time with the labels.

Comment: Put the `* 100` within brackets `(int)(tracker.GetProgress() * 100.0)`. Otherwise it would convert the progress (0 to 1) to int first and multiply 100 later so you can only get 0 or 100.